# Orange3.2 Classification Tree Viewer - Print

Tags: orange

I have Orange3.2 installed on Python 3.4 32-bit.  I have built a Classification Tree and can view it with the Classification Tree Viewer widget.  I want to print the graphical version of the Classification Tree.  I've tried to Save the Graph as a .png file as provided for in the widget, and I get a .png file, but with 0 (zero) bytes.

Any suggestions as to how I can print or save this graphical representation of the Classification Tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Can you try on some small tree first?

Otherwise, try Report. You should get a report which includes the image of the tree (hopefully - if this works). In the Report window, use Save to get an html with embedded image. Open it in browser and save the image.

Comment: Yes!  Size does matter!  :>)  I just tried it with a smaller tree and it worked fine.